Is possible to find all SPL Tokens or NFTs Collections where an solana address is the Mint or Update authority only providing this address or keypair?
Is there a way to, for example:

I provide an solana address.
Find all the SPL Tokens where this solana address is the Mint or Update Authority, or NFT Collections where this solana address is the Mint or Update Authority.

If is not possible by Solana Address, is possible using their Keypair?

You never provide a keypair directly to any external program. Your keypair contains your secret key. Providing this to a third party gives them the ability to control your assets.

This RPC call will fail because most servers don't allow calling getProgramAccounts with the SPL Token program, but if you had your own unbounded RPC node, you could do getProgramAccounts with a memcmp filter for the supply:
    let mut program_accounts_config = RpcProgramAccountsConfig {
        account_config: RpcAccountInfoConfig {
            encoding: Some(solana_account_decoder::UiAccountEncoding::Base64),
            ..RpcAccountInfoConfig::default()
        },
        ..RpcProgramAccountsConfig::default()
    };

    // Use server-side filtering if only one vote account is provided
    program_accounts_config.filters = Some(vec![
        // Filter by mint authority
        RpcFilterType::Memcmp(Memcmp::new_base58_encoded(4, &pubkey_to_search)),
        // Filter by size 82, which is the size of an SPL token mint
        RpcFilterType::DataSize(82)
    ]);

    let all_mints = rpc_client
        .get_program_accounts_with_config(&spl_token::id(), program_accounts_config)?

Adapted from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/32e8ad2149a9e1af9c67defd342140707629a256/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L1868
